# How to extend DocumentManager of JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I would like to add my own custom behavior (server-side) to the closing tab(s) operation, so I think I should extend this method `closeFile()` of the 
`DocumentManager` https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/docmanager/src/manager.ts#L177.

I have a custom file browser plugin (extension) that works well if I use it with JupyterLab's core IDocumentManager but not if I use it with the extended/overwritten IMyDocumentManager like here:

```
const browserPlugin: JupyterLabPlugin<void> = {
  id: "my:fs",
  requires: [IMyDocumentManager, ISettingRegistry, IMainMenu],
  activate: activateMyBrowser,
  autoStart: true
};
```

My `IMyDocumentManager` looks like this:

```
import { IDocumentManager, DocumentManager } from '@jupyterlab/docmanager';
import { Token } from '@phosphor/coreutils';

export interface IMyDocumentManager extends IDocumentManager {}

export const IMyDocumentManager = new Token<IMyDocumentManager ('@jupyterlab/docmanager:IDocumentManager'); 

export class MyDocumentManager extends DocumentManager implements IMyDocumentManager {
   closeFile(path: string): Promise<void> {
    console.log("Test override a method for closing: " + path);
    return super.closeFile(path);
  }
 }
```

When I load JupyterLab in the browser I get the error:

[image]

It's probably because I have to define the Token differently. Instead of `new Token<IMyDocumentManager ('@jupyterlab/docmanager:IDocumentManager')` I should use some other string than `'@jupyterlab/docmanager:IDocumentManager'` but I don't really know what. It's hard to infer from the PhosphorJS code.